# If an item within a Row is not visible how to lay it out?

Tags: qt, qml, visibility

As per the Doc

> If an item within a Row is not visible, or if it has a width or height
>   of 0, the item will not be laid out and it will not be visible within
>   the row. Also, since a Row automatically positions its children
>   horizontally, a child item within a Row should not set its x position
>   or horizontally anchor itself using the left, right,
>   anchors.horizontalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors. If you need to
>   perform these actions, consider positioning the items without the use
>   of a Row.

I couldn't find the best solution for it. Could anyone help me in this regard? See my below code:

```
Rectangle{
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    Component{
        id:itemDelegate
        Item {
            id: itemId
            width: listView.width; height: listView.height * 0.20
            Row{
                spacing : listView.height * 0.20
                Repeater{
                    model:5
                    Column{
                        Button{
                            text: index
                            //opacity: (index % 2) === 0 ? 1.0:0.0
                            visible: (index % 2) === 0 ? true:false
                        }
                        Button{
                            text: index
                            //opacity: (index % 3) === 0 ? 1.0:0.0
                            visible: (index % 3) === 0 ? true:false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView{
        id:listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors {
            left: parent.left; top: parent.top;
            right: parent.right
            margins: parent.width * 0.08
        }
        delegate: itemDelegate
        model:aaModel
        clip:true
    }
}
```

In the output the first indexed Column will be invisible. Hence it won't be laid out and second indexed Column will occupy that space. But I want blank space there. However I can achieve that using opacity at a cost of blank space in third indexed Column (first blank space followed by a button). But I want such a behavior that lifts buttons up in the column if button is not visible along side if all the buttons in Column are invisible the blank space should appear at the place of Column. So here Columns inside the Row would not help me. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp the Button in an `Item`

```
Column {
    Button {
        text: 'Blue'
    }
    Item {
        width: greenButton.implicitWidth
        height: greenButton.implicitHeight
        Button {
            id: greenButton
            visible: false
            text: 'Green'
        }
    }
    Button {
        text: 'red'
    }
}
```

To make it easier, create a custom component for it (*e.g. MyButton.qml*):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    id: root
    property alias button: myButton
    implicitHeight: button.height
    implicitWidth: button.width
    Button {
        id: myButton
    }
}
```

---

Use it like this:

```
Column {
    MyButton {
        button {
            text: 'green'
            onClicked: button.visible = false // Won't shrink the column
        }
    }
    MyButton {
        button {
            text: 'red'
            visible: false
        }
    }
    MyButton {
        button {
            text: 'orange'
            onClicked: visible = false // Will shrink the column
        }
    }
}
```